# How to convert hash of hashmaps to json in java

Tags: java, json, list, hashmap, gson

Hi I have nested object with consisting of hashes and lists. I am trying to use gson but doesnt seem to work well if the values in hashmaps are hashmaps instead of simple strings.

```
Map questionDetails = new HashMap<>();
questionDetails.put("label", descriptionNode.getText());
questionDetails.put("validations", new HashMap<>().put("compulsary", 1));
System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(questionDetails));
```

if prints

```
{"label":"I am working on something"}
```

while

```
Map questionDetails = new HashMap<>();
questionDetails.put("label", descriptionNode.getText());
questionDetails.put("validations", "something");
System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(questionDetails));
```

seems to work well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it is not working is that you put the result of: new HashMap<>().put("compulsary", 1) instead of a hasmap itself.

```
questionDetails.put("validations", new HashMap<>().put("compulsary", 1));
```

do:

```
Map questionDetails = new HashMap<>();
questionDetails.put("label", descriptionNode.getText());
Map validations = new HashMap<>();
validations.put("compulsary", 1)
questionDetails.put("validations", validations);
System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(questionDetails));
```

> {"validations":{"compulsary":1},"label":"I am working on something"}

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 new JSONObject(map);
```

Other functions you can get from its documentation
http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html